# Let $f(x)=x^7-7x+3\in{Q[x]}$, show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $Q$

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x)=x^7-7x+3\in{Q[x]}$, show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $Q$

I searched on internet and this polynomial is called Trinks' polynomial. I was trying to use Eisenstein's criterion to show it is irreducible, but it does not work.

Anyone can help me on this question?

Answer (score 2):

Find the factorization of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just note that Eisenstein criteria actually works, but you need to perform $f(x+a)$ substitution first, and the polynomial is rather ugly. In this case for example
$$
f(x-3)=x^7-21x^6+189x^5-945x^4+2835x^3-5103x^2+5096x-2163
$$
is Eisenstein with $p=7$.